# Returning to first cell at end of macro

Tags: excel, vba

simple question that I can't figure out. I have a basic macro does the below, however I can't get it to return to the start point + one column to the right.

[image: In the end the macro will be run 25x but need to get into the correct finishing point.]

- Copies a column starting at B2.
- Adds that data to the bottom of the data in Column 1.
- Returns to the starting cell and then moves one across.

Looking at the picture, Green is where I start, I then copy the column to orange, and then want to move to the red cell to the right of Green

```
Sub MOVE_COLUMN_TO_ROW1()

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: My recommendation would be to start by reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Use `Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Scroll:=True`

Comment: Isn't that just going to go to the A1 cell unless I define the starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints to work with assuming the following:

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long 'Use a variable to capture the last used row
Dim lc As Long 'Use a variable to capture the last used column
Dim x As Long 'Use a variable to loop through all used columns
Dim arr As Variant 'Use a variable to capture values you want to transfer

With Sheet1 'Be, at least, explicit about a worksheet object using its CodeName

    'Getting the last used column from the 1st row using xlToLeft
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Loop from 2nd column to the last used column
    For x = 2 To lc

        'Catch the last used row in the current column(x)
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row

        'Fill the array to use in your data transfer
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(lr, x))

        'Catch the last used row in the first column
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'Transpose the found range underneath last used row of column 1
        .Cells(lr + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr

    'Continue with the next column
    Next x

End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

---

Notice that the code is quite extensive and can be written much more compact, but my goal is/I'm hoping that you'll be able to understand each step of the process this way.

Good luck, happy coding =)

Comment: I have copied that code but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Will it work given I am starting at B2

Comment: Have you written down the correct CodeName for the sheet you want to refer to? @Scottyp

Comment: Crap sorry I didn't see that, have changed 'sheet1' to 'ActiveSheet'.